Establish connection to a bluetooth module
I try to establish a connection to a BT-module in cpp, which worked so far. See the following sequences:
// Create Bluetooth Address for target device
SOCKADDR_BTH socketAddress;
ZeroMemory(&socketAddress, sizeof(socketAddress));
socketAddress.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
socketAddress.serviceClassId = SerialPortServiceClass_UUID; // Serial Port Profile (SPP)
socketAddress.btAddr = stringToBthAddr(connection.address);
    
socketAddress.port = 1; // BT_PORT_ANY for dynamic port allocation

// Socket Connect
SOCKADDR_BTH socketAddress = createBluetoothSocketAddress(connection);
logInfo(LOG_TITLE, connection.address, "Connecting to Bluetooth device.");

ret = connect(connection.socket, reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR*>(&socketAddress), sizeof(socketAddress));

if (ret) {
    int errorCode = WSAGetLastError();
    string errorText = getErrorMessage(errorCode);
    logError(LOG_TITLE, connection.address, format("Connecting to Bluetooth device failed. Error [{} - {}]", errorCode, errorText));
    ret = BTH_ERROR_BLUETOOTH_CONNECT_FAILED;
}
// ...

The interessting part is here socketAddress.port = 1
For my currently used BT-Modules I could establish the connection without any issue, but now I got a new Module (BT-122) and this always rejects the connection with the following error message.
Failed to connect; [10064] A socket operation failed because the destination host was down.

My solution to fix that was to change the port to: socketAddress.port = BT_PORT_ANY
And everything works again. I just want to understand the background. Could this be a wrong configuration in the BT-Module itself? How can I check which port is free? And the crazy thing is, if I use BlueCove (Java BT wrapper) only the ports 1-30 are allowed. BUT: BT_PORT_ANY is a define by '-1'. Don't understand the background of this behavior.
